# What is the name and meaning of the integral of potential energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, potential, schroedinger-equation, terminology

The paper, [Significance of Electromagnetic Potentials in the Quantum Theory](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.115.485) by Aharonov and Bohm makes reference to a term, $S$. I'm curious as to if this term has a name and to its meaning.

$S$ is the integral of energy over time, shown literally and through the wave equation on the first page of the paper.

$$ψ=ψ_0 exp((-iS)/ħ)$$ and $$S=∫V(t)dt$$

where $V(t)$ is some potential.

References to $S$ exist throughout the paper, and while I understand the concept of the A-B effect, I can't grasp any of the proper physics from this.

Comment: It's called the "eikonal": 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_approximation#Formal_description

Comment: @Buzz, please take a look at David Z's answer here:  [Answering in comments](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/9887)

Comment: @Buzz could you post that as an answer? Comments really aren't supposed to be used for answering the question.